# Multibitrate rtmpe not working in jwplayer which has akamai secure streaming

Tags: token, jwplayer, live, akamai, smil

I want to switch from the old OpenVideoPlayer to JWPlayer 7.3 to get better results on my webcasts. We are using Multibitrate RTMPE stream with Akamai Live secure streaming, but within JWPlayer, I only got the "No playabe sources found" (http://webdiffusion.pjcformation.com/evenement/DetailsTest/71/).

To make it work in OpenVideoPlayer (http://webdiffusion.pjcformation.com/evenement/DetailsTestOpenVideo/71/), we create the token from the Akamai API, put it in a variable, then add it at the end of our streamname (see SMIL file below). We create a dynamic SMIL with the 3 streams (multibitrate) to the url /evenement/smil/71/

Akamai told us it is a player issue and JWPlayer doesn't understand at all our problem 
   So you, how did you manage the token? Here is our code and the SMIL file:

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var filePathNotEncoded = '/evenement/smil/71/';

    var tokenOnly = 'dbFaSaWaHbKbjaodoawckcEbbdqajd2aOaM-bxnEBE-Dta-fjLWa-zDCCuFtD';
    var aifp = 'ab345';

    var playerInstance = jwplayer("my-video");
    playerInstance.setup({
       provider: '/assets/client/js/plugins/jwplayer-7.3.6/AkamaiAdvancedJWStreamProvider.swf',
        file: filePathNotEncoded,
        height: 540,
        width: 960,
        skin: { name: "vapor" },
        primary: "flash",
        autostart: true
    });
</script>
```

**SMIL:**

```
<smil>
<head>
   <meta base="rtmpe://xxxxxxx.live.edgefcs.net/live/" />
</head>
<body>
   <switch>
       <video src="Streamname_1@sxxxxxx/?auth=dbFaSaWaHbKbjaodoawckcEbbdqajd2aOaM-bxnEBE-Dta-fjLWa-zDCCuFtD&aifp=ab345" system-bitrate="300000" />
        <video src="Streamname_2@sxxxxxx/?auth=dbFaSaWaHbKbjaodoawckcEbbdqajd2aOaM-bxnEBE-Dta-fjLWa-zDCCuFtD&aifp=ab345" system-bitrate="800000" />
        <video src="Streamname_3@sxxxxxx/?auth=dbFaSaWaHbKbjaodoawckcEbbdqajd2aOaM-bxnEBE-Dta-fjLWa-zDCCuFtD&aifp=ab345" system-bitrate="2400000" />
    </switch>
 </body>
</smil>
```

Please help, JWPlayer isn't able to help us and Akamai told us that our code is right (it were working with OpenVideoPlayer from Akamai)

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Hi Matt, what JW Player license are you using? Enterprise and above is required for AES Encryption: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1430261-aes-content-protection

Comment: Hi Josie, 

   I am using the Entreprise version. But JWPlayer technical support seems to have never experimented a Multibitrate stream with token authentification.

  They don't understand why we are using a swf provider and they keep telling me to change from RTMP to HLS. So I will try that and keep this post updated.